# Experimental procedure for predicting post-emission alpha particle path

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, kinematics, lagrangian-formalism

I want to model the 1D trajectory of an alpha particle post-emission. The alpha particle will be emitted in a cloud chamber and the particle will move over a coordinate plane that I will use to measure the distance that it traveled in the x-axis over time *t*. I will then use this information to solve for *p* by using:
\begin{equation}
t=\frac{L}{c}\sqrt{\frac{m^2c^2}{p^2}+1}
\end{equation}
I will use the momentum to determine the particles overall energy and then determine the classical Lagrangian equations of motion, which I will compare to a quantum prediction of the path by using the propagator.

Could this procedure work, or do I need another way to determine the momentum?

Comment: You lost me after "and then determine the classical Lagrangian equations…" but you have to be careful that the particle will loose enough energy/momentum as it propagates through the cloud chamber as to invalidate your equation. Moreover is your plan to use a high speed camera? Otherwise, I don't see how you would measure the timing…

Comment: I was planning on using a high-speed camera to get precise timings. I'm confused by what you mean by, "you have to be careful that the particle will lose enough energy/momentum as it propagates through the cloud chamber as to invalidate your equation."  Do I need to be concerned about the particle losing too much energy, or too little?  Also, what specifically confuses you. I would love to add clarification, but I would like to know your specific misunderstanding.

Comment: Your equation assumes $p$ is constant but the particle will be stopped in the cloud chamber, no? So your equation is only valid for small enough segments of the track. But I guess you realised that after all. As for my other remark, it would have been more accurate to state that you did not give enough details for me to have a clear idea of what you want to do.

Comment: @LucJBourhis   I see what you mean now.  Basically what I want to find is an "equation of motion" by using QM principles, but that obviously is complicated by the probabilistic nature of QM.  The closest substitute I found was the propagator. Would that work in this context? I'll edit the question to clarify, also.

Comment: Do you realise how difficult it is to model the interaction of the alpha particle with the matter in your cloud chamber? I suggest you consult, for example, this [NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Star/Text/programs.html) page discussing the databases for the stopping power for alpha particles (and protons). I am pretty sure that there is no ab-initio computation from first principles actually, only phenomenological models fitted to data.

Comment: But by all means I don't want to discourage you: a cloud chamber with a high speed camera, this is a really cool project!!

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis  Could I use the NIST data to approximate the relationship, or could I use the Bethe formula to calculate the stopping power. I want to be sure I understand you, also. If there is a way to calculate or model the stopping power, that would allow for me to correct my formulae for the loss in energy as the system progresses; is that correct? Thanks for the encouragement!

Comment: Bethe formula is a very good approximation about a couple of Mev for alpha particles iirc. Below that, it gets really bad. So your mileage may vary. If you happen to have to deal with both sides of that threshold, you could use Bethe for energetic enough alpha and a fit to NIST data below the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-rv4m3Tykw) to see what the tracks look like coming from a source, [or this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FS2pKyRKeYs)  from the ambient environment.

You can check the ionization formulae if you manage to find the velocity by using a fast camera.

[This is a photo with tracks](http://practicalphysics.org/alpha-particle-tracks-bent-very-strong-magnetic-field.html) in a strong magnetic field perpendicular to the picture,  which will help in the accuracy of determining p.

It gives an easier way to find the momentum from the radius using Bqv=mv^2/r and taking into account the ionisation loss.

[image: alphamag]

You seem to have a misunderstanding

> then determine the classical Lagrangian equations of motion,

Suppose you have the momentum and know the ionisation loss, a straight line is the solution even if you use the whole aparatus of the lagrangian equations.

> which I will compare to a quantum prediction of the path by using the propagator.

The only quantum prediction I can imagine on the path is the small scatters and ionization losses which have a quantum mechanical description. There is no quantum prediction for the origin of the track, other than the decay probability of the nucleus that gave rise to it, and that you cannot get from one track.

If you are thinking of wavepackets in quantum field theory, the width/thickness of the ionisation path is much larger than the size of the packet (estimated by using the heisenberg uncertainty)

Comment: I now see the flaws in the “boringness” of the tracks. Would analyzing the path under the effect of a magnetic field be more interesting? That would also give me a more precise measure of momentum, as you point out of (which is also how they determine the momentum at ALICE).  Also, do you suggest that I just abandon the QM approach, and just stick with the classical method, or is there a better QM approach.

Comment: As I said , I cannot see a quantum mechanical approach because on individual tracks or particles it it probabilistic. Only measured distributions are predicted by quantum mechanics, not trajectories. Quantum field theory makes wavepackets  which with creation and annihilation operators model the propagation of a particle , but this is the same as the classical trajectory in a cloud chamber or bubble chamber. Our detectors are macroscopic per force ( unless we go to nanotechnology)

Comment: My interest in this project is seeing how the models compare. If they are the same that is fine for my purposes, it still provides me with valuable information. My real question is simply about the possibility of using the propagator to model the path.

Comment: Would this be more interesting by using background radiation instead of a source? The main issue I see with that is difficulty in finding initial conditions for the equations.

Comment: Do you have a link for this "propagator" of yours?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, as I only know of one propagator in QM (see below). However, after further research, I'm not sure if the Wigner function would be more appropriate. Please excuse my inexperience on this topic, this is clearly not my expertise.       [1]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator

Comment: The propagator cannot model a path. At best it will give a probability for finding a particle at  (x,y,z). That is not a path comparable to other paths. Only probability distributions can be compared.

Comment: What about the Wigner function?

Comment: Look, how old are you? The wigner function is about path integrals that have very little to do with particle paths. They are a method of integrating so as to get the quantum mechanical probabilities, in the quantum case, and particles are quantum entities. I think you should start studying courses, this is no handwaving thing. try the mit online courses which are  designed to make a physicist online.  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/#physics

Comment: I have been watching the OCW lectures. Most of the information I have is from another user,  it you are making me think that he had no idea what he was talking about. I have the original post below. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/363256/172430

Comment: the answer is ok , you are misunderstanding the terms. Amplitude is not a measurable quantity , it has to be complex conjugate squared and it will give the probability distribution for finding a particle at (x,y,z) at time t.